# WSDL for other protocols different than SOAP?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

From wikipedia:

> The Web Services Description Language
>   (WSDL, pronounced 'wiz-dəl') is an
>   XML-based language that provides a
>   model for describing Web services.

But in most cases, I found that WSDL is used in conjunction with SOAP. but as far as I know, if the WSDL is a language to describe web services. there should be possible to describe another kind of web services **different** from SOAP. is this possible? any examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WSDL 1.1** is for **SOAP only**, where **WSDL 2.0** can be used for REST as well. Additionally there is a similar description language for **REST based** web services called [**WADL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language).

Neither WSDL 2.0 nor WADL are yet widely used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WSDL 2.0 to describe a [REST](http://www.google.com/search?q=rest+wsdl) web service.

There exist binding for [CORBA](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/omg-adopt-corba-wsdl-spec-796) as well.